# How to set Data with document editor in CKEditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

I create a system to save the document by cookie, everything works well, but I just miss how to put the text on the document ... I have a DecoupledEditor, but when I try to make DecoupledEditor.setData (cookie) it tells me that setData does not exist! Have a nice day

```
DecoupledEditor.setData(docu);
```

To get the editor

```
DecoupledEditor
    .create( document.querySelector.....
```

Comment: `DecoupledEditor.create()` returns a promise, you can call `setData` from the return promise. `DecoupledEditor` itself does not have the `setData` method

Comment: Okay, but I don't know how to do that unfortunately. But thank you for your help anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.

```js
(async function() {
  try {
    const editor = await DecoupledEditor
                   .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ));
    editor.setData('This text is generated from setdata() method.');
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
 })();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/23.0.0/decoupled-document/ckeditor.js"></script>

<h1>ckeditor</h1>
<div  id="editor">
   Default Text
</div>
```

[Doc Refrenence](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/basic-api.html)

Comment: Ok, but I would like to do this in a variable because I would like to make sure that when you press a button the text changes with the contents of the cookie. And you too know how to do with the getData(). Thank you for your reply!

Comment: `editor` is your variable. so when a button is pressed, you do `editor.setData('your cookie content')`, and you get the current content with `editor.getData()`

Comment: Yes, I enter this as code: ```function setDD(){
  editor.setData('Hi There');
 }``` And here's the mistake I get:```Uncaught ReferenceError: editor is not defined``` (I am on DecoupledEditor)

Comment: This is more like a 'Javascript 101' question than Library specific. Look up `Javascript variable scope`, then you should be able to answer your own question.